# Создать интернет магазин без CMS

Tags: php, html

Добрый вечер, товарищи. Суть проблемы в следующем - нужно создать сайт, что то наподобие интернет магазина, который будет связан с базой данных, хранящейся на этом же компьютере. Но есть 1 момент - нельзя использовать все известные (да и любые вообщем-то) CMS. Как вы наверное уже догадались, я студент, и на данный момент не очень разбираюсь в данной теме. В связи с этим хотел спросить у тех, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, с чего начать знакомиться с предметной областью. Может какие то ссылки на статьи или сайты посоветуете, где довольно хорошо разжеван данный материал. Заранее благодарен и извиняюсь за возможно неправильно поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Гуглите обучалки по php, html, css, mysql. Установите связку apache, mysql, php и вперед за ордена

Comment: А без css разве никак не обойтись? Мне упор не на сайт надо делать, а на базу данных...

Comment: без css, конечно, можно, но оно некрасиво выглядеть будет.

Comment: Ну то что вы посоветовали, оно и понятно. Просто в сети огромное кол-во обучалок, а хотелось бы чего то конкретного, того, по чему может вы сами учились.

Comment: мануал, что @IntegralAL советует. Ну и гугл или хешкод, если что не ясно из там написаного

Answer (score 3):

Доброго времени суток! Ну что могу сказать, что я тоже проходил в свое время этот путь. Тут надо изначально знать на достаточном уровне язык php. Изучайте [мануал php](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/index.php) и другие источники по php. Непосредственно по интернет-магазину, могу предложить следующие ссылки:

- [Пишем интернет магазин на php](http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/pishem-internet-magazin-na-php.html)
- [Документ по интернет-магазину](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fem-sut.spb.ru%2Fdownloads%2Fdoc_download%2F52-php-&ei=iBWNU9ORB-aA4gT994H4CA&usg=AFQjCNEPt4H3wnw47H7RhimH-kaMTsNhFQ&sig2=nfLEOfE_1IngaLTtY5eo9w&bvm=bv.68191837,d.bGE&cad=rja)
- Ну и еще ищите на ютубе видео по разработке интернет-магазинов от разных инициативных людей, не стесняющихся поделиться опытом с начинающими.